# Error when building libsecp256k1 for Rust

Tags: ink, rust, blockchain, phala

I am trying to use the `libsecp256k1` library in a no-std environment and I get the following error when building the contract:

```
[wasm-validator error in module]  unexpected true: memory max >= initial, on memory
```

It seems like this happens while using the recover function only -> The main problem is to try and recover a public key given an ethereum  signature and message.

```
libsecp256k1 = { version="0.7.1", default-features = false, features = ["static-context"] }
```

It looks like I need the static-context feature to be able to use the recovery function, however, after digging through the source code, it seems like recovery actually calls recovery_with_context, which actually adds an additional parameter - context, defined like this

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "static-context", not(feature = "lazy-static-context")))]
/// A static ECMult context.
// Correct `pre_g` values are fed into `ECMultContext::new_from_raw`, generated by build script.
pub static ECMULT_CONTEXT: ECMultContext =
    unsafe { ECMultContext::new_from_raw(include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/const.rs"))) };


#[cfg(all(feature = "static-context", not(feature = "lazy-static-context")))]
/// A static ECMultGen context.
// Correct `prec` values are fed into `ECMultGenContext::new_from_raw`, generated by build script.
pub static ECMULT_GEN_CONTEXT: ECMultGenContext =
    unsafe { ECMultGenContext::new_from_raw(include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/const_gen.rs"))) };
```

Please note, that since this example is meant for the Phala Ink! environment, no standard libraries can be used. Alternatives are also welcome - I just want to extract the public key from the signature and message, as stated before.

```
pub fn recover_pubkey(&self, v: u8, r: Vec<u8>, s: Vec<u8>, message: Vec<u8>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too, a few weeks ago. This is an issue of the library.

See https://github.com/paritytech/libsecp256k1/issues/134.

I can use sp-io's functions which are some host functions. But I'm not sure if that works for ink.

Comment: I didn't manage to find the solutiom to this, so I switched to pink-web3, which supports most of what I need anyways.

Comment: Phat Contract offers common signature signing and validating feature (secp256k1/ecdsa, sr25519, ed25519). You can use the chain extension in the environment here: https://docs.rs/pink-extension/0.4.1/pink_extension/chain_extension/signing/index.html